# Moqui relationship between entity and database table

Tags: moqui

Is there a way to create relationship between entity and database table in Moqui?

If no? Is there a way to create `ViewEntity` between entity and database table in Moqui and show data and search in it? If relation between tables exist in database how can I use these tables to show data and search in Moqui?

Comment: A relationship between an entity and a database table doesn't make sense: an entity in the Moqui Entity Facade is a representation of a database table. While you can always use JDBC directly, to use the Entity Facade to access a database table you just define an entity that represents it. If the table matching the entity name (or table name specified in the entity definition) already exists Moqui won't create the table so you can use this on existing tables.

Comment: thanks for reply i do the same.